# How to print to a network printer with IP address

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have finished an app that using printer.

this is code of printing:

```
this.printDocument1 = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
this.printDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;
this.printDocument1.Print();
```

now I have a printer named XXX, and which has IP address 192.168.2.200

#### My question

how can I print to that printer please?

Thanks

#### Update

```
this.printDocument1 = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            this.printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "MainPass";
            this.printDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
            printDocument1.PrintPage += printDocument1_PrintPage;
                this.printDocument1.Print();
```

and then the `printDocument1_PrintPage` is :

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("PANTRY KOY", valueFont, Brushes.Black, width, height);


            printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `PrintDialog` instance, that implies you are letting the user select a printer, and you need to respect the printer chosen there. (hint: you can set the initial printer shown in the dialog, through the [`PrinterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printername.aspx) property of the dialog's [`PrintSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.printersettings.aspx) property). After that, I bet that if you scan through [the documentation for the PrintDocument Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument_properties.aspx), you'll see what you need to do to set the printer (hint: the IP Address doesn't matter, but the PrinterName does).

Comment: I don't want the user to select the printer at all. I want to print automatically, I will update the code for you in order to see if this printdialog really do something or I added it without any helpful

Comment: please check now, I updated my question, what should I do in order to remove any dialog. I don't want the user to select the printer, I want to do that automatically